# Xcode Simulator: how to remove older unneeded devices?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I'm running Xcode 4.3.1 iOS-Simulator which originally only supports iOS 5.1.

I need to test my code with iOS 4.3, so I used Xcode's "Install" feature to install it as described in ["Installing Xcode with iOS 4.3 device simulator?"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47323)

Now I'm finished with testing but cannot find a way to uninstall the 4.3 portions ("iPhone 4.3 Simulator" and "iPad 4.3 Simulator"). I want to reduce the clutter in the Scheme menu.

No one on Apple's Xcode listserv knew the answer!

EDIT: note that much has changed since Xcode 4.3, so suggest anyone reading this look at all the answers. The newest ones such as Steve Moser's may be of more use to you!

EDIT 10/2017: Posted on Twitter by Julio Carrettoni‏

> If you are an iOS developer, execute this:
>   `$ xcrun simctl delete unavailable`
>   It removes old simulators Xcode no longer use. For me it was 6Gb
>   Did not try it myself...

[Also, I just saw Russ Bishop mentioned this in a comment below already...]

Answer (score 184, accepted):

Did you try to just delete the 4.3 SDK from within the Xcode Package?

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs

please also delete the corresponding .dmg file in

> ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/Downloads

to [prevent Xcode from re-installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672945/xcode-4-4-simulator-how-to-remove-older-unneeded-devices/11790983#11790983) the same package again.

---

for XCode >= 6 see  [@praveen-matanam 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30206853/529977)

Comment: This won't work in xcode 4.5.2. As soon as you start again the compiler it will ask you to install older legacy devices again. Cancel will quit xcode so you are forced to install again.

Comment: That's right Alejandro, Apple seems to have changed the "license thing" so that you always need a valid developer account and you have to install all extensions again and again on every major update within the app.. legacy systems are mostly unsupported too ;(

Comment: @AlejandroLuengo do you know if this was fixed in 4.6? If not I'll put a bug report in. I've just studiously avoided installing any legacy devices since my first bad experience!

Comment: See Dan Reese's answer below for something that works on Xcode 4.6.

Comment: Worked for Xcode 6.3.1, along with this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/30206853/286618. Cleared old documentation and saved 9GB!!!

Comment: Good solution for old XCode version. For up-to-date version, check out Praveen's answer!

Comment: Still working as of September 2018, under macOS 10.13.6 and Xcode 10!

Comment: No such file or directory

Answer (score 239):

In Xcode 6+ you can simply go to Menu > Window > Devices > Simulators and delete a simulator  you don't need.

Comment: The question was relevant in version 4 and probably 5. As you can see it was quite difficult. I avoided using older simulators since then myself.

Comment: That is correct. If you want the simulators to be "really gone" or reinstall them in Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads you have to delete the simulator runtime as pointed out below http://stackoverflow.com/a/30206853/1344293

Comment: Thanks this is the easiest way to manage the simulators. instead of deleting the simulators from the xcode folders. This works for me :)

Comment: How do you delete a device with an older iOS version? The devices window only shows simulators with iOS 9.1 (on Xcode 7.1). I would like to avoid editing device_set.plist and removing folders in Finder.

Comment: You can also use this script to recreate simulators: https://gist.github.com/cabeca/3ff77007204e5479f7af

Comment: Correct, it will delete a simulator from Xcode. What it won't do is delete the simulator from your Mac to release the massive amounts of space they take up.

Answer (score 228):

### October 2020 update

As was mentioned, you can use `xcrun` to do a few things:

- `xcrun simctl list devices` or `xcrun simctl list --json` to list all simulators
- `xcrun simctl delete <device udid>` to delete specific device
- `xcrun simctl delete unavailable` to remove old devices for runtimes that are no longer supported

More things you can do with `xcrun` (see code snippet)

```html
- `xcrun simctl boot <device udid>` to launch (multiple) simulators
- `xcrun simctl io booted recordVideo — type=mp4 ./test.mp4` to record simulator video
- `xcrun simctl io booted screenshot ./screen.png` to make screenshot of simulator
- `xcrun simctl openurl booted https://google.com` to open URL in simulator
- `xcrun simctl addmedia booted ./test.mp4` to upload photo or video file (for photos app)
- `xcrun simctl get_app_container booted <your apps bundle identifier>` to find the app container (where identifier is like *com.bundle.identifier*)
- `xcrun simctl help` to explore **more** commands
```

### Original Answer

September 2017, **Xcode 9**

#### Runtimes

You will find them here:

```
/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes
```

[image]

#### Devices

To delete devices go here:

```
~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices
```

Much easier to delete them use Xcode:
Xcode->Window->Devices and Simulators
[image]

Helping Xcode "forget" about runtimes and prevent from re-installing them - delete .dmg file(s) here:

```
~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/Downloads
```

I hope it will help someone

Comment: Please do not delete devices from the filesystem; use `xcrun simctl delete <device udid>`. You can also run `xcrun simctl delete unavailable` to remove old devices for runtimes that are no longer supported.

Comment: I don't have ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/Downloads (no Downloads folder in ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/), wonder why

Comment: the folder path you listed doesn't exist, Xcode 9.4

Comment: This is what I was looking for: not deleting 12.2 simulated devices one-by-one, but delete the entire 12.2 simulator from the system. The path worked with XCode 10.3. After deleting, I had to restart it, and the count of the simulators just halved.

Comment: I can't believe there isn't still just a "Delete" or "Uninstall" button in the IDE!.....

Answer (score 168):

In Xcode 6 and above, you can find and delete the simulators from the path `/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes`. Restart Xcode in order to take effect (may not be needed).

Comment: 6.4 here. Needed to restart my machine for it to take effect.

Comment: 7.2 - no restart required

Comment: xcode 8.0 needed a restart to clear the invalid simulators in the devices window

Comment: On macOS Sierra and Xcode 8.2, that path does not exist on my computer.

Comment: @thiagoveloso it is because you didn't installed any other version of simulators, but iOS 10.0+. I have had there only 9.3, 8.4 and 8.3 `.simruntime` files

Comment: I can be also in `~/Library/Developer/...`

Comment: Don't remove all!

Comment: This is how you delete old simulator runtimes! Perfect answer! Apple should make an easier way to do this through the UI. If you mark the check box in Xcode preferences to install an old simulator runtime, uninstalling it should be as easy as unchecking the box.

Answer (score 92):

Run this command in terminal to remove simulators that can't be accessed from the current version of Xcode (8+?) in use on your machine.

`xcrun simctl delete unavailable`

Also if you're looking to reclaim simulator related space [Michael Tsai](https://twitter.com/mjtsai/status/1022838770494832643) found that deleting sim logs saved him 30 GB.

```
~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator
```

Answer (score 27):

Xcode 4.6 will prompt you to reinstall any older versions of the iOS Simulator if you just delete the SDK. To avoid that, you must also delete the Xcode cache. Then you won't be forced to reinstall the older SDK on launch.

To remove the iOS 5.0 simulator, delete these and then restart Xcode:

1. /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/PhoneSimulator5.0.sdk
2. ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode

For example, after doing a clean install of Xcode, I installed the iOS 5.0 simulator from Xcode preferences. Later, I decided that 5.1 was enough but couldn't remove the 5.0 version. Xcode kept forcing me to reinstall it on launch. After removing both the cache file and the SDK, it no longer asked.

Comment: A slightly more precise answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11790983/209371), though I haven't tested it myself yet.

Answer (score 26):

I had the same problem.  I was running out of space.

Deleting old device simulators did NOT help.

My space issue was caused by xCode.  It kept a copy of every iOS version on my macOS since I had installed xCode.

Delete the iOS version you don't want and free up disk space.  **I saved 50GB+ of space.**

[image]

---

---

**NOTE** -> can't you see `~/Library` inside `Finder`?  It is hidden by default.  Use `Terminal` and type `cd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS\ DeviceSupport/` or google how to see hidden folders.

---

---

**NOTE** -> if you have multiple users on a single macOS machine, make sure to find the directory ONLY with the user account that originally installed xCode.

Comment: I count 9G above - how did you recover 75G?

Comment: hi @DavidH - 75GB was before my clean-up.  As I have been working with xCode for years, xCode had silently installed every variant of iOS 7, 8, 9 and 10 on my machine. In reality I probably only need iOS10 and iOS11, going forward.

Comment: The folder does exist with xCode 9.4 @PeterCullen.  You just have to access it from the user account who originally installed xCode. I have two user accounts on my Mac that share xCode. Only the user account that installed xCode can view this folder.

Comment: I am accessing it with the account that installed Xcode. It's not there.

Comment: are you opening Finder and selecting "Go to folder"?  Library is a hidden folder, by default.

Comment: I ran `xcrun simctl delete unavailable` as suggested in other answers but that didn't delete the actual iOS versions. Thanks for the tip, there were a bunch of old/in-between ones in that folder! Btw, there's an app called "DevCleaner" in the app store that lists everything and can also delete specific ones (including old logs and archives).

Answer (score 24):

## 2024: macOS Sonoma & Ventura

Same as the previous version search **storage** in your spotlight search tool and then double click the **Developer** option.

The interface looks a bit different now

[image]

## macOS Big Sur & Monterey before 2023

We can use the Storage Management tool:
**⌘ + Space bar** and search storage.

Under Developer: you can find Xcode Cache and build files and also old version of iOS support files that you can delete.

[image]

Tested on macOS Big Sur & Monterey

Answer (score 11):

following some of the answers here, deleting some simulators from my Xcode Menu > Window > Devices > Simulators did nothing to help my dying disk space:
[image]

however, `cd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS\ DeviceSupport` and running `du -sh *` I got all of these guys:

```
2.9G    10.0.1 (14A403)
1.3G    10.1.1 (14B100)
2.9G    10.3.2 (14F89)
1.3G    10.3.3 (14G60)
1.9G    11.0.1 (15A402)
1.9G    11.0.3 (15A432)
2.0G    11.1.2 (15B202)
2.0G    11.2 (15C114)
2.0G    11.2.1 (15C153)
2.0G    11.2.2 (15C202)
2.0G    11.2.6 (15D100)
2.0G    11.4 (15F79)
2.0G    11.4.1 (15G77)
2.3G    12.0 (16A366)
2.3G    12.0.1 (16A404)
2.3G    12.1 (16B92)
```

All together that's 33 GB!

A blood bath ensued

see more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29930198/can-i-delete-data-from-ios-devicesupport)

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATE Xcode 14**

In Xcode 14, you can finally uninstall Simulator runtimes via the "Platforms" section in settings. Just select one and hit the minus "-" button in the lower left corner.

Comment: Handy, but note that it doesn't cover the extra support files (and of course not the caches and project build files) as noted in https://stackoverflow.com/a/69623427/954643. And if one wants to go that far in wiping files, you should also wipe unneeded data in `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/` with `xcrun simctl delete unavailable` to remove the Devices whose runtimes you removed with this setting feature, which can free up gigabytes of space depending on how aggressively you use multiple runtimes and devices.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to @childno.de answer, your Mac directory

> `/private/var/db/receipts/`

may still contains obsolete iPhoneSimulatorSDK `.bom` and `.plist` files like this:

> `/private/var/db/receipts/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK8_4.bom`
>   `/private/var/db/receipts/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK8_4.plist`

These could make your Downloads tab of Xcode's preferences show a tick (`√`) for that obsolete simulator version.

To purge the unwanted simulators, you can do a search using this bash command from your Mac terminal:

> `sudo find / -name "*PhoneSimulator*"`

Then go to corresponding directories to manually delete unwanted SimulatorSDKs

Answer (score 6):

In XCode open Window - Devices, then select and remove the outdated simulators.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote up one-line bash script that would delete **ALL** your simulators:

```
xcrun simctl list devices | grep -E -o -i "([0-9a-f]{8}-([0-9a-f]{4}-){3}[0-9a-f]{12})" | xargs -L1 xcrun simctl delete
```

- `xcrun simctl list devices` will list all the simulators installed on your machine
- `grep -E -o -i "([0-9a-f]{8}-([0-9a-f]{4}-){3}[0-9a-f]{12})"` will grab the device UUID
- `xargs -L1 xcrun simctl delete` will attempt to delete the device for each UUID it found

If you want to see everything it'll execute, you can add `echo` before `xcrun`, i.e.

```
xcrun simctl list devices | grep -E -o -i "([0-9a-f]{8}-([0-9a-f]{4}-){3}[0-9a-f]{12})" | xargs -L1 echo xcrun simctl delete
```

Answer (score 4):

Some people try to fix it using one way, some the second. Basically, there are 2 issues, which if you check them out & solve both - in 99% it should fix this issue:

1. Old device simulators located at `YOUR_MAC_NAME` (e.g. `Macintosh`) -> `Users` -> `YOUR_USERNAME` (`daniel`) -> `Library` -> `Developer` -> `Xcode` -> `iOS Device Support`. Leave there, the newest one, as of today this is `13.2.3 (17B111)`, but in future it'll change. The highest number (here `13.2.3`) of the iOS version indicates that it's newer.
2. After this list your devices in `Terminal` by running `xcrun simctl list devices`. Many of them might be `unavailable`, therefore delete them by running `xcrun simctl delete unavailable`. It'll free some space as well. To be sure that everything is fine check it again by running `xcrun simctl list devices`. You should see devices only from the newest version (here `13.2.3`) like the screenshot below shows.

[image]

As a bonus which is slightly less relevant to this question, but still free's some space. Go to `YOUR_MAC_NAME` (e.g. `Macintosh`) -> `Users` -> `YOUR_USERNAME` (e.g. `daniel`) -> `Library` -> `Developer` -> `Xcode` -> `Archives`. You'll see many archived deployed application, most probably you don't need all of them. Try to delete these ones, which are not being used anymore.

Using these 2 methods and the bonus method I was able to get extra 15 GB of space on my Mac.

PS. Simply deleting simulators from Xcode by going to `Xcode` -> `Window` -> `Devices and Simulators` -> `Simulators` (or simply `CMD` + `SHIFT` + `2` when using keyboard shortcut) and deleting it there won't help. You really need to go for the described steps.

Answer (score 4):

1. Open Xcode --> Go to Window (from menu bar) --> Devices and Simulators
   --> Click on Simulator --> Right-click on the simulator that you want to delete --> Click Delete
2. To delete any unwanted simulators that you installed in the past as an *extra Component* through Xcode.

- Open Terminal
- Type ***open /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes***
- Delete undesired simulators

Answer (score 3):

Another thing you can do is to change the Deployment target to the highest value.  This will prevent the Scheme Menu from displaying older versions.

To do this go to:
Target->Summary then change the Deployment Target.

Comment: Maybe things changed since I posted the question, but when I did, you would see the different simulators in the Scheme menu, and it just complicated choosing the right one.

Answer (score 3):

I tried all answers. None of them worked for me.

What worked for me on Sierra + Xcode 8.2 was going to:

`/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices` and deleting all devices.

(Maybe this won't work for you, maybe this *is* a solution as a standalone, or maybe you have to do this in addition to other answers, but I did all solutions here and so not sure what did the deed). Just be aware that some of the answers here are old and the location of simulator has changed. [Snowcrash's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39944791/5175709) seems to be most recent.

Comment: Can I assume you shut Xcode down first, did this, then restarted Xcode?

Comment: @DavidH sorry I don't remember what I did. I had the issue for 3-4 weeks. Each time it was happening when I was switching between projects/sim-devices...I just tried everything and this seemed to do it for me...again it could something else for you

Comment: @DavidH did you also try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30206853/5175709)

Comment: For Xcode 10 and newer the folder is: `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with these answers is that, with every Xcode update, menus and locations will change.

Just go to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms` and delete what you don't need. Xcode will start fine. If you're at all concerned then you can simply restore from Trash.

Comment: I seriously doubt that Xcode downloads simulators you request it its bundle. Surely they go into the users library, no? That said, I have never downloaded an older one since I had my issue with Xcode 4.

Comment: For each Platform (iOS, watchOS, AppleTVOS, MacOS) I have 2 folders: I have "iPhoneOS.platform" & "iPhoneSimulator.platform" Which one am I suppose to delete? I checked with colleague, he had exactly both of them but no issue.The reason I'm actually here is because of [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39856001/xcode-8-beta-simulator-fails-to-run-app-after-accidentally-running-xcode8-simula) and someone told me it's because I have 2 simulators/Xcodes, but If I've dont it correct I've deleted my other version of Xcode and also I've deleted the 9.3 runtime...

Comment: Please please please do not do this. No one should be messing with content inside the Xcode bundle.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac, check /Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS\ DeviceSupport

[image: iOS DeviceSupport]

Comment: Current versions of Xcode use a slightly different location: `/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following snippet to delete unavailable runtimes:

```
echo "rm -rf $(xcrun simctl list runtimes -j |\
      jq ".runtimes[] | select(.isAvailable|not) | .bundlePath" | xargs)"
```

to execute, remove `echo` or add `| bash` at the end.

If you don't have `jq` command available, you can get it using `brew install jq`

Answer (score -2):

Command+Space

Type 'simulator'

open the old beta simulator you no longer need.

right-click on it in the dock, then choose Options>'Show in Finder'

Close the app, then remove it from the folder.

:)