# How to remove older unneeded devices?

Tags: xcode4, ios-simulator

So this is related to a prior question I posted - [how to remove 4.3 simulators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10834817/96716). I stupidly installed the iOS 5.0 Simulator, and now the technique offered in my last post does not work. When you remove the 5.0sdk, then restart Xcode, it forces you to install the legacy simulators or quit.

I even deleted Xcode 4.4 and re-installed it to no avail (it must store my unfortunate choice deep in the preferences file).

The reason I want to get rid of it is that the Scheme popup now has 5 options in it instead of 3, making it a real pain to test a Universal App.

**EDIT:**

When I cd to `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/Downloads` I see:

```
$ ls

Xcode.SDK.iPhoneSimulator.5.0-5.0.0.1.dmg
Xcode.SDK.iPhoneSimulator.5.0-5.0.1.1.dmg
eded78df8bfabaf6560841d10cf8e53766f74f28.dvtdownloadableindex
f7133e82a08bdb4ebf724f16beed2bbac2a265cf.dvtdownloadableindex

$
```

I have both Xcode 4.4 and 4.5DP3 on my machine, so assume that the first two files are one per Xcode release - in any case I moved both to /tmp.

The earlier suggestion had been to remove:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In addition to removing the iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk folder, delete the corresponding .dmg file in `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/Downloads`. Then Xcode will not force you to reinstall it anymore.

Comment: I'm really curious as to how you discovered this! Thanks so much!

Comment: Sorry to keep badgering you, but then, how did you trip over my question - it was posted so long ago??? [I'm giving you as many points as I can as we go!] I've thought that it would also be useful to go look at older unanswered questions, but haven't found an easy way to do that on SO.

Comment: Just by chance - saw one of your interesting answers - clicked on your user account - saw this question

Answer (score 1):

Do the following in terminal:

```
cd ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/Downloads
ls
```

You'll see the files now; then run the bash command to remove them.