# How to uninstall iOS 5.0 Simulator from Xcode 4.5

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

I've installed Xcode 4.5, and since I write apps for fun, I don't intend to support older iOS versions, and to save space on a 500 GB iMac, is there anyway to delete it?

Comment: Removing the iOS 5 SDK will save a lot more space than removing the simulator itself.

Comment: This other post worked for me (make sure to delete the cache) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834817/xcode-simulator-how-to-remove-older-unneeded-devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тry to delete iPhone/iPhoneSimulators from supported platforms in Xcode package:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms

Comment: please also delete the corresponding .dmg file in

~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/Downloads

to prevent Xcode from re-installing the same package again.