# Xcode version unable to install the application on ios simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ios-simulator, osx-mavericks

I just upgraded my mac os from mountion lion to mavericks version 10.9.3 . In mountion lion i used Xcode 5.1 with ios simulator 7.1, 7.0 , 6.0 and 6.1 . I had a back up this xcode 5.1,which i installed to new mavericks version. Now if i run the project using the ios simulator 7.1 ,it shows iOS Simulator failed to install the application. Does it have anything to do with Xcode versions installed for the os versions

Comment: Have you tried: 1) Restarting the simulator 2) Cleaning the simulator 3) Restarting Xcode 4) Restarting your Mac 5) Updating Simulators 6) Updating Xcode?

Comment: @LordZsolt i tried 1,2 and 3 .Shall try out rest !

Comment: Please add the xcode alert

Comment: @gran33 Similar to the one in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982315/xcode-5-issue-ios-simulator-failed-to-install-the-application

Answer (score 0):

Reset your simulator like this:

[image]

Force Quit the simulator in the Activity Monitor.

U can try also remove the simulator ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12653876/how-to-uninstall-ios-5-0-simulator-from-xcode-4-5)) and re-install it