# Xcode 6.4, component not actually downloaded

Tags: xcode6

I was downloading for example the 8.3 component ...

[image]

the bandwidth broke off, so it was not downloaded.  (The files are not there when you look.)

However, Xcode indicates a tick.

Is there a way to force it to download it again, or, clear that tick?

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834817/xcode-simulator-how-to-remove-older-unneeded-devices). I think there is info how you can manage that. **I did not try this myself**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually try this:

In Xcode 6, you can find and delete the simulators from the path /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes. Restart Xcode in order to take effect. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834817/xcode-simulator-how-to-remove-older-unneeded-devices/30206853#30206853)

Comment: sweet !  that did it.  interestingly Xcode does appear to have saved the already-downloaded half of the gb-size download; it continued where it left off, and then installed it properly.  Thanks