# Why is Xcode Caches so huge?

Tags: xcode, macos-big-sur

I updated macOS to Big Sur for my late 2016 MacBook Pro.

When I check the storage:

[image]

Xcode Caches takes a huge size of storage. I deleted it and it will show up again.

Why is it so huge? Can I delete them and how to delete them?

Comment: Where did you get that information from?

Comment: About This Mac -> Storage -> Manage..

Answer (score 7):

They are not caches. But simulators for various devices like AppleTV, Watch, and iPhones.

You can delete them from the app.

[Xcode Simulator: how to remove older unneeded devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834817/xcode-simulator-how-to-remove-older-unneeded-devices/25991239#25991239)

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-hd-space

Comment: At one second I think it works but now it shows up and occupies the storage by 9.25GB again.. ! Thanks for the advice anyway and I'll still try to figure out WHERE the storage is going to, LOL

Comment: @Elvin watch out for your bandwidth. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/377220/xcode-simulator-constantly-download-something 
Also, actual size of Xcode may differ from what finder/ about this mac shows. Consider using something like disk inventory X to analyse what's inside the ~/Library/Developer and Xcode.app. Or plain old `du`

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-hd-space

Comment: I tried everything I get for deleting Xcode Caches and it keeps coming back..

Comment: Have you tried seeing the insides of Xcode.app and ~/Library using disk inventory ?

Answer (score 3):

That whole file that you see labeled **Xcode Caches** listed within the **Developer** tab after you've decided to view the **storage management**, is not all comprised of Caches. It has iOS simulators and inside there are caches of the simulators. To delete those caches, you can use [CleanMyMacX](https://cleanmymac.com/). Open the app, and select *space lens* then navigate to the *Developer* folder within the *Library* folder. Select *CoreSimulator* and inside you'll find the *Caches* folder which is the one that you should delete.

Comment: According to CleanMyMacX (it's a great app by the way), the exact path for these HUGE Xcode caches is "~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Caches". I deleted everything in it, then I started to use Xcode to run some projects I needed. After a while, these HUGE caches are back..!! Are these HUGE caches necessary? If it's a yes, I'll just pass over this question.. anybody?

Comment: They are necessary for the performance of the simulators, just so it takes a while to complete the first retrieval of all necessary files to run the first iteration of your app and then it uses the cached files for the subsequent iterations.

Comment: I see, thanks for all the helpful informations.