# How to delete old simulators

Tags: xcode

How do you remove old Simulators

[image]

As it takes up space not used

[image]

(Thanks @Ali Yiğit Taş)

I found `iOS 15.2.simruntime` in `/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes`

But I am running 15.4

[image]

Comment: "DevCleaner for Xcode".app might be of help here, since new Xcode add its iOS support for its perticular version (and watchOS, etc), but never delete the old ones.

Comment: Great tool, it did the trick

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Xcode, Window> Devices and Simulators> Simulators.
You can delete simulators here that you don't want.

[image: Simulators]

Also, can you try to check /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure it is the same -  it is the type of devices not the actual simulators. You can see I have both simulators 15.2 & 15.4?

Comment: Can you try to check /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes

Comment: Hmm, in there is: iOS 15.2.simruntime. Strange as I do have 15.4 running. I recently upgraded to Xcode Version 13.3.1 (13E500a)...

Comment: I see the latest versions are not in that list you have posted. Maybe the latest versions are located in a different folder I think.

Answer (score 9):

Go to Xcode -> Settings... -> Platforms to select and then delete old simulators using the [-] button or right-clicking:
[image: Xcode Settings Platforms]

Answer (score 0):

Found that you can use ["Storage Manager"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834817/xcode-simulator-how-to-remove-older-unneeded-devices) and or "DevCleaner" Thanks @Larme

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to

> Xcode > Menu > Window > Devices & Simulators > Simulators

Click on simulator and check iOS version. If you want to delete that simulator, right click on simulator name and click delete in popup dialog.

That's it.

[image]